# Can't connect with SqlConnection

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

What is wrong with my code or connection string? Always can't connect to database.

```
string c = null;
SqlConnection sql;

c = "Data Source=127.0.0.1, 3306;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=testowa;User ID=kuba;Password=123";

sql = new SqlConnection(c);

try
{
    sql.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Connected!");
    sql.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("not connected :(");
}
```

Comment: Check: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ to see what connectionstring you need.

Comment: Why don't you do MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException?.Message ?? ex.Message); instead.

Comment: Or just connect your database with Visual Studio and see it's connection string on properties window? And use `using` statement to dispose your connection automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

Comment: Strange, port 3306 is usually reserved for MySql not SqlServer which uses instead 1433

Comment: It may help to see the exception message.

Comment: It is mysql server on XAMPP and it says the port is 3306

Comment: Then you are totally on the wrong path. You should use the connection string for MySql and use the appropriate classes in the MySql NET connector

Comment: ex message says it's critical error, number 18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to connect to a MySql database not to a Sql Server one. These are two different products and require different connection strings, different classes and different ADO.NET Providers.

- First, download and install the MySql Connector/NET [from here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)
- Second, go to your project references and add a reference to
  `MySql.Data.dll`
- Third, remove the `using System.Data.SqlClient` and add `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient` in every source file where you have the database code
- Fourth, change your code to use the appropriate classes like
  `MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand, MySqlDataReader, etc...`

Finally, use a proper connection string for MySql

```
using(MySqlConnection sql = @"Data Source=127.0.0.1; 
      Database==testowa;uid=kuba;Pwd=123;Port=3306"))
{
    try
    {
        sql.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connected!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("not connected :(" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Permissions or firewalls

Comment: Already solved thanks :)

Comment: It's just testing db but ok